How to detect a circle with uncertain thickness and some noise in an binary image?
The input image is here : the input image
I try to use cv2.HoughCircles in opencv-python to find the expected circle, but the result is noise as in this picture : result in param2=0.2
the code is:
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image.png')
# apply GaussianBlur
kernel_size = (15, 15)
sigma = 0
blurred_image = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, kernel_size, sigma)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(blurred_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT_ALT, dp=1.5, minDist=20, param1=50, param2=0.2, minRadius=100, maxRadius=400)

# draw the result
if circles is not None:
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for i in circles[0, :]:
        cv2.circle(img, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.circle(img, (i[0], i[1]), 1, (0, 0, 255), 3)

# show the result
cv2.imshow('used image', gray)
cv2.imshow('detected circles', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

If i set param2=0.8, then no any circle can be found!
What should I do to get a better result that fit the further perfect circle in the example picture above?
The "perfect circle" can be defined as follows:
Given an angular resolution of 0.1 degrees, the area will be divided into 360/0.1 = 3600 segments.
A perfect circle includes as many sectors as possible, where these sectors contain pixels with grayscale values below a certain threshold (e.g., 15).
In other words, the goal is to have the proportion of sectors that meet the criteria as close to 1 as possible.
If there are multiple resulted circles with same proportion, any one of them can be considered a perfect circle.
An example "perfect circle" : perfect circle

What is for you the perfect circle?

The problem is that your "perfect circle" isn't quite a true circle so that to fit it properly the fitting code needs the extra degrees of freedom provided by an ellipse. Two of the three green circles fitted are not far off right depending on exactly what fitting criteria you have opted for. I'd prefer one that stays inside the black zone as much as possible but as ever YMMV.

@Tino D Thank you for your comment. The "perfect circle" is defined as described above.

As shown in the added picture, we can see the image contain a true circle. My purpose is to find a circle rather than an ellipse. "Two of the three green circles fitted" can be selected using the proportion of them. Do you have any better methods for finding the perfect circle?   I look forward to your response   ^_^   @Martin Brown

Does it have to be with Hough?

This is sort of a static solution for now, but if you always have such nice contrast and you can accuretly get the coordinates, then fitting a circle with least square might not be such a bad idea:
def fit_circle(x, y):
    A = np.c_[x, y, np.ones(len(x))] # design matrix A with columns for x, y, and a constant term
    f = x**2 + y**2 # get the function as x²+y²
    C, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(A, f, rcond=None) # optimize
    cx = C[0] / 2 # get the centre x coordinate
    cy = C[1] / 2 # get the centre y coordinate
    radius = np.sqrt(C[2] + cx**2 + cy**2) # calculate the radius 
    return round(cx), round(cy), round(radius) # return everythin as int

To use this function, I did the following:
im = cv2.imread("circle.png") # read as BGR
imGray = cv2.imread("circle.png", 0) # read as gray
y, x = np.where(imGray==0) # get x,y coords
cx, cy, r = fit_circle(x,y) # get the circle properties, center and radius
im = cv2.circle(im, (cx,cy), r, (255, 0, 0), 5)
im = cv2.line(im, (cx-r,cy), (cx+r,cy), (0, 255,0), 2)
im = cv2.line(im, (cx,cy-r), (cx,cy+r), (0, 255,0), 2)
im = cv2.circle(im, (cx,cy), 10, (0, 0, 255), -1)
cv2.imwrite("WithCircle.png", im) # save im for stack

The result:

As I said, very important that you can get those nice pixels that define your circle, this method can work with some added noise as well I presume, but definitely not good if you have any one-sided deviations.

derivation of the math, for the curious: How to find the center of circle using the least square fit in python?

Here is another approach to fit a circle using Python/OpenCV/Skimage.

Read the input
Convert to grayscale
Threshold and invert so ring is white on black background
Apply morphology open to remove small specks
Use Skimage to skeletonize to the center line of the ring
Draw skeleton points on copy of input
Get the external contours of skeleton image and draw white filled on black background
Use skimage region props to get the circle center and diameter
Draw circle on copy of input
Save results

Input:

import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import regionprops
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize


# load image and set the bounds
img = cv2.imread("circle_ring.png")

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold and invert
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# apply morphology open
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
binary = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=2)

# thin binary input
skeleton = skeletonize(binary)
skeleton = (255*skeleton).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# draw skeleton on copy of input
skeleton_img = img.copy()
points = np.column_stack(np.where(skeleton.transpose() > 0))
for point in points:
    cv2.circle(skeleton_img,tuple(point),1,(0,0,255))

# find contour and draw on input (for comparison with circle)
cnts = cv2.findContours(skeleton, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
c = cnts[0]

# draw white filled contour on black background
filled_contour = np.zeros_like(binary)
cv2.drawContours(filled_contour, [c], -1, 255, -1)

# find radius and center of equivalent circle and draw circle
# see https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops
regions = regionprops(filled_contour)
circle = regions[0]
yc, xc = circle.centroid
radius = circle.equivalent_diameter / 2.0
print("radius =",radius, "  center =",xc,",",yc)
xx = int(round(xc))
yy = int(round(yc))
rr = int(round(radius))

# draw circle on copy of input
result = img.copy()
cv2.circle(result, (xx,yy), rr, (0, 0, 255), 1)

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("circle_ring_thresh.png", thresh)
cv2.imwrite("circle_ring_skeleton.png", skeleton_img)
cv2.imwrite("circle_ring_fit.png", result)

# display it
cv2.imshow("image", img)
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("binary", binary)
cv2.imshow("skeleton", skeleton_img)
cv2.imshow("filled_contour", filled_contour)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)

Threshold image:

Skeleton image on copy of input:

Circle result on copy of input:


You can use cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT instead of cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT_ALT
Notice: the third and fourth parameter in cv2.HoughCircles, cannot set higher values. Because you set zoom-in to an 80% or probably low resolution monitor.
Snippet:
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('circle.png')
output = image.copy()
img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2.99, 755)


if circles is not None:
   circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
   print(circles)
    
   for (x, y, r) in circles:
      cv2.circle(output, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 2)
 
cv2.imshow("circle", output)
 
cv2.waitKey(0)

Screenshot:

